# Reloading multiple elements by a timetable

Tags: javascript, function, refresh, onload

I have an active desktop website that I am trying to use that uses multiple javascript onload call functions. These functions are needed for:

1. A calendar date and time clock.
2. A time block function (e.g. if the time is 12:00:00 pm it *should* say "Lunch time").
3. A news feed scroller.

My problem is two-fold: Firstly, if the news scroller loads, then the date and time is missing, but the time block function still exists. Secondly, and quite possibly for a different thread, is that the date and time doesn't refresh the time block function, even though it has to refresh itself every second. Is there a function I'm supposed to use to automatically refresh the time block function to what time of day it is? They're both in the same table cell, but no frames have been used. Is it because they're not sharing the same div? Or do I have to reformat it to a frame instead?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and any further information I'll be more than happy to elaborate on.

My code now:

```
function start() { 
  oncontextmenu="return false;";
  feedreader.run(); 
  date_time('date_time');
} 
window.onload = start;
```

Cheers,
MJ

Comment: paste some code, html markup, best to make jsfiddle

Comment: Yes, good idea, I shall have to extract it out tonight in order to re-post tomorrow. Fidding with the javascript sounds like the most likely option, and I'm still a (re-learning) newbie. I'm thinking it's a syntax issue too. I may as well say now: The date and time function is called from an external .js file, whereas the timeblock function is in-page. Although I struggle to believe that would make a difference.

Comment: check in dev console, if here are syntax errors

Comment: Okay good news. Multiple reload has been fixed, courtesy of using only ONE onload event in the script and not two. I was using a body onload tag to run the date and timeblock functions, then the news feed would use a window onload function after it's script. This would nullify the date but not timeblock. It's a moot point - the real problem was using the onload function twice in the script, so I  queued them up after the final call (newsfeed) was made, using fairly normal convention:

Comment: may be you delete this question and ask new as this one seems not a question anymore...

Comment: Nope.... I accidentally used the enter key and it accepted my message as as finished. Not so... The code looks like the following: function start() {
   oncontextmenu="return false;";  
   feedreader.run();
   date_time('date_time');
}
window.onload = start;                                                  But unfortunately, I haven't managed to have the timeblock function refreshed as soon as the appropriate time is showing. I am going to upload this page to a web server in the next couple of days to make it easier to understand. Until then, thanks for your enthusiasm and willingness to help.

Comment: what is `oncontextmenu` here ?

Comment: Its a simple command to stop the context menu (that is, the right click menu). Not so sure why I bothered, it's not so bad... By the way - thanks for your suggestion, but I'm not sure how a question is deleted, but yes, the remaining problem I have would probably be found out elsewhere. I'll look again before asking again. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Nice! While it still works as it is, it would be more correct if it was using the document tag instead. However, Google Chrome seems to ignore the function and gives a right click menu anyway XD                  I think I'll get over it.

Comment: `document.oncontextmenu=function() {return false;}` works in chrome.